# python: flat list of dict values

Tags: python

I have a `list` of `dicts` like so:

```
a = [ {'list':[1,2,3]}, {'list':[1,4,5]} ]
```

Am trying to get a flat set of the values in the `list` key like `{1,2,3,4,5}`. What's the quickest way?

Answer (score 4):

You can write a  loop like:

```
result = set()
for row in a:
    result.update(row['list'])
```

which I think will work reasonably fast.

Or you can simply use *set comprehension* and that will result in the following *one-liner*:

```
result = {x for row in a for x in row['list']}
```

In case not all elements contain a `'list'` key, you can use `.get(..)` with an empty tuple (this will reduce construction time):

```
result = {x for row in a for x in row.get('list',())}
```

Comment: @SethMMorton: yeah for some reason I'm already mixing the different comprehensions up the entire day ;).

Comment: I must say, I do think the set comprehension is way clearer than my `itertools` solution.

Comment: @SethMMorton I agree, but I think `set.union` might be even cleaner

Comment: @Chris_Rands: not given you need to invoke the `set` constructor, construct an empty dictionary `{}` each time (even if it is not necessary) and have to use parameter expansion I think. The idea is nice, but there is a lot of noise around it that makes it less clean. The performance could be boosted if the `.get(..)` takes the empty tuple as default, since it that case it only has to pass a reference.

Comment: `row.values()[0]` will work as long as each dict has a single entry.

Comment: Hmm you might be right, Willem, +1 for your answer anyway :)

Comment: @TemporalWolf That's not even valid in Python 3

Comment: @TemporalWolf: not in Python-3.x since that will return an iterable (that does not support indexing) and furthermore it is *very* error prone since the smallest change to the dictionaries will let it fail/crash.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem `{num for b in a for x in b.values() for num in x}` works in Python 3 and supports empty dicts and multiple value dicts.

Comment: @TemporalWolf: that is because here you use `.values()` without the `[0]` index and because all dictionaries have **one** value. The point is that from the moment the specs are a tiny bit different, this will fail dramatically. One of the properties of good software engineering is that an algorithm is robust: that it needs no/small modifications for small differences in specs.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem [repl.it](https://repl.it/Fj2r/0) disagrees. Whether it's better or worse than the given solution I can't say, but it is a valid alternative.

Comment: @TemporalWolf: question: "*Am trying to get a flat set of the values in **the `list` key***". How is this the correct answer?

Comment: @TemporalWolf The fact that the example you provide in the link results in an answer that includes values *not in the "list" key* demonstrates that it is NOT a valid alternative.

Comment: Given the OP didn't specify whether the dict contains any other keys (and whether or not they should be included) it's conjecture on our part which solution is correct. Both are accurate for the example, although I admit the OP seems to favor your solution. They solve different problems, I agree.

Answer (score 3):

It is not clear what your definition of "quickest" is, but whether it is speed or number of lines I would use a combination of itertools and a generator.

```
>>> import itertools
>>> a = [ {'list':[1,2,3]}, {'list':[1,4,5]} ]
>>> b = set(itertools.chain.from_iterable(x['list'] for x in a if 'list' in x))
```

Note that I have added a guard against any elements that may not contain a `'list'` key; you can omit that if you know this will always be true.

Answer (score 1):

### flat list can be made through `reduce` easily.

All you need to use *initializer* - third argument in the `reduce` function.

```py
reduce(
    lambda  _set, _dict, key='list': _set.update(
          _dict.get(key) or set()) or _set,
    a, 
    set())
```

Above code works for both python2 and python3, but you need to import reduce module as `from functools import reduce`. Refer below link for details.

- [for python2](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#reduce)
- [for python3](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.reduce)